# Is it possible to make the reinforcement learning agent output 4D actions?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Is it possible to make the agent output 4D actions? I mean, there are three actions possible (0, 1, 2), but they should be combined in four dimensions.

ex) Context-bandit situation

input_t1: [0, 1, 2, 0]

input_t2: [2, 0, 1, 0]

output: [1, 2, 0, 0]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use MultiDiscrete actions (from gym.spaces)

```
self.action_space = MultiDiscrete([number_of_possible_actions for _ in range(self.number_of_action_dimensions)])
```